# How to Host Multiple Websites with Different Domain Name on a Single Web Hosting Account

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, responsive-design

I am having this question in mind where what kind of mechanisms or recommended solutions that suits my question's scenario.

So far I discovered [iframe](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp) that was not so suitable because of website responsiveness issue.

Then I proceed to explore on [responsive iframe](http://npr.github.io/responsiveiframe/) and implement it to the multiple websites where the iframe is able to adapt to dynamic height and width of the physical screen size. Sadly, the result is not positive where it change some of the website animations become misplace and images display in funny sizes.

Appreciate for any help. Thanks.

Comment: are you asking about hosting or some webpage with other peoples sites mashed together?

Comment: Too less informations. Do you have root permissions? Can you access te vhost file, are you running an apache server?

Comment: @JaromandaX I need to make all the websites (different domain names) that have the ability to adapt iframe because iframe have the ability to mask the URL under one web hosting account. But the problem is iframe kills website responsiveness. So i am curious on what is the good industrial practice when comes to my question mentioned above.

Comment: @SebastianNette I am running on Apache server for local testing and GoDaddy Web Hosting. I am not able to access to the vhost file that you mentioned.

Comment: No idea what you're asking for... Normally, depending on the server technology you only have to map a domain name to a physical folder in the filesystem of your web server... the IFRAME stuff makes no sense... or your question is misleading.

Answer (score 1):

Normally if you have multiple web sites on different dns entries your web hoster will have a facility to setup the path to the website you want for each domain. If you want to hide the domain to the different websites (I wont ask why) then you have two options.

Firstly use an iframe as previosly discussed. You can set the width of the iframe to 100% and make sure it has a container sized according to the viewport.  However this solution will always have some problems as you have discovered.

Or Secondly use a reverse proxy to serve up the destination website into the page. See [here](https://uk.godaddy.com/help/how-to-set-up-a-reverse-proxy-12303) on instructions for a reverse proxy on godaddy. this is for tomcat but a similar principal applies. it looks like apache is used in godaddy so there is plenty of documentation arround that on the web e.g. [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-apache-http-server-as-reverse-proxy-using-mod_proxy-extension) .

The reverse proxy is the best solution, but it does require you have a dedicated server account, and a bit of tech know how.